# Finding the tangent line using implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

My professor wrote this problem on the board as a challenge:

> Find the tangent line at (0,0) to the curve defined implicitly below.
>   $$\ln(1+x+y)=\left( x^{42} e^y +  \cos(xy)\sin(xy)\right)^{2015} \left( ye^{x\cos y} + 429 \sin(y \cos(x))\right)^{257} + 2x$$

I tried differentiating the equation, but I gave up because it was just too messy.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: i don't believe this exercise serves any useful purpose; in fact it is useless. you might want to find the tangent line of $x^2 - xy + y^2 = 1$ .

Comment: My professor said that there is a trick to it.  I am already comfortable with problems like yours.

Comment: your prof must be a genius; don't take his/her word for it. press for details. come back and tell us all about it.

Comment: Ok. I won't be seeing him until next week.  I was just very curious, since he said that he can do this in his head in half a minute!

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%28ln%281%2Bx%2By%29%3D%28x^42e^y%2Bcos%28xy%29sin%28xy%29%29^2015%28ye^%28xcosy%29%2B429sin%28ycos%28x%29%29%29^257-2x%29%2Fdx)

Comment: I don't think that's what Herbert had in mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$\ln(1+x+y)=f(x,y)^{2015}g(x,y)^{257}+2x$$

Now differentiate:

$$\frac{1+y'}{1+x+y}=2015y'f'(x,y)f(x,y)^{2014}g(x,y)^{257}+257y'g'(x,y)g(x,y)^{256}f(x,y)^{2015}+2$$

Since $f(0,0)=g(0,0)=0$,
$$1+y'=2$$

Comment: Great!  I think we can just let $F=f^{2015}$ and $G=g^{257}$ and deal with $F$ and $G$, right?  Then $F'G+FG'$ at $(0,0)$ is $0$.